# Angular assets images sometimes give 404

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, assets

I tried just to move some images from paths like:
\assets\styles\pics
to
\assets\styles
And they gave 404 error.

I don't understand why some paths inside assets folder failed when trying to load images from them.

Any advice?

Please find next a screen shot about what is happening, when requesting the image alone the browser returns automatically to root page localhost:4200 like the Angular routes is working

[Screen shot of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0BNp.jpg)

Comment: First guess would be you have references to \assets\styles\pics and those that fail expect that path which is no longer valid since you moved them? Pretty broad question though since we can't see a way to reproduce it.

Comment: Actually I have only references to /assets and favicon, I don't know what to share cause its really a strange problem. Why just some paths aren't working inside assets. Maybe its a reserved words? Or I don't have angular-cli file.
Any hints about files handlers here or where to manage these configurations?

Comment: I'd probably start by looking at the network tab on your developer tools and look at the 404 path of where it's trying to GET from compared to where the files actually live and compare that path string to the instances where it's failing at reference in your img src tags / background-image css urls.

Comment: Already did that, its some how Angular routing engine is working for some paths.